# Adding doctype for html5 (or any doctype) breaks my site

Tags: css, html, debugging, doctype

Adding a doctype to any of the photo series pages (salmon,buddy,bleach,watercolors) breaks the page and causes the divs' fixed-attachment background images to not appear .

I'm not sure if this is how this site works but if anyone could help me figure out which parts of the site aren't working outside of quirks mode (in any browser) I'd really appreciate it.

here is a live version of the site and a link to it hosted on github:

http://emilyduda.pancakeapps.com/stories.html

https://github.com/Michaelzrobin/duda-2-beta/tree/gh-pages

I know I should have started by having my doctype declared--the code has a lot of bugs and i didn't plan the website very well ,since i designed it as i coded it, and i'm new to both. I have lots of messy styles and superfluous stylesheets, and a lot of debugging and refactoring to do, but i'd like to see if i can deal with this doctype problem without having to completely recode the site, first.

Comment: Welcome to SO. can you make a fiddle? posts with links to pages does no one any good in the future should that site change...

Comment: i'm not sure i can make a fiddle since it has a few different stylesheets and scripts it depends on? any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern web pages are required to have a doctype. Without one you go into [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and it's like 1995 all over again causing you to have a broken [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). This is why the very first thing to write onto any new page is the doctype.

[Here is a link explaining many of the different modes.](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/) Scroll down for the title "Effects" to see how quirks affects browser layout.

Your only course of action is to bite the bullet and add the doctype and fix all your markup because you will do nothing but fight an uphill battle from here on out.

Comment: thanks for your reply-- i have added the doctype, what i'm having trouble with is finding out what styles or markup isn't rendering correctly once it's out of quirks mode

Comment: @michaelzr Depends on the style but read my link about quirks mode. Margins and such are placed differently when you are there which is why everything will be misplaced. You never want to be in quirks mode.

Comment: i've skimmed through that page and I'll look through it more carefully  in a bit. i felt like it had to do with the divs background-image being fixed attachment...not sure where margins could come into play. but yeah im really having trouble figuring out what's not up to html5 standards. ive been tinkering with this project so long that i really can't see the forest for the trees at this point :/ . thanks for your input

Comment: If you want to know what the effects are, go to my link about the different modes and scroll down about one-third for the headline of "Effects".

Answer (score 6):

**Short Answer:** If `<!DOCTYPE html>` breaks your format, check whether your use of the `%` unit is involved, and/or whether replacing `%` with either `vw` or `vh` might help.

Just adding my 2-cents' worth here in case it helps someone else.

I had a web page made *without* `<!DOCTYPE html>` that was working well, i.e. formatting properly. At one point I added in `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the height got screwed up. To make a long story short, I eventually figured out that, without `<!DOCTYPE html>`, a height calculation that included `100%` was working properly, but when `<!DOCTYPE html>` was added, it broke. I converted `100%` to `100vh` and, voila, the page formatting worked again.

I haven't worked through (and won't work through) the reasons why this happens, but maybe it has something to do with the `%` unit behaving differently in quirks mode than it does in the modern "non-quirks" mode. For example, maybe in quirks mode, the `%` is relative to something other than the element's parent object like, say, the viewport...but I'm only guessing. In any case, if `<!DOCTYPE html>` is breaking your formatting, consider investigating your use of the `%` unit and whether using `vw`/`vh` instead of `%` might be more appropriate.

Comment: LOL spent hours figuring this out for my site. Apparently you can't calculate 100%. I re-wrote a dynamic height from `height: calc(100% - 115px);` to `height: calc(100vh - 115px);` and not it works!