# DOCTYPE issue with CSS height

Tags: css, html, doctype

The problem is that I was working so fast that I forgot to add the DOCTYPE declaration, now I add it, and my website becomes a mess, this is the example:

```
<div class="container" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task Filter" id="task_filter">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:scroll;width:100%;padding:1%;height:50%;border:solid 1px #cdcdcd" id="task_card_container">
    </div>
</div>
```

There are loads of elements like this, so I can't just start reengineering the whole HTML, I need a way for this piece of code to show as it does in Quirks mode, but with a proper DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: where do you put the doctype?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding doctype for html5 (or any doctype) breaks my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036087/adding-doctype-for-html5-or-any-doctype-breaks-my-site)

Comment: @cssGEEK — In the correct place because otherwise it wouldn't have changed the way that the page was rendered.

Comment: Since you say that you have many elements with similar behaviour - then maybe reengineering HTML won't take as long?

Maybe you can set the height for container? Maybe you can go for JS solution if nothing helps?

Comment: @Olga you're right that's what I did, however it took me 1 hour, and well, you know that in a job one has to work fast, maybe I wouldn't have forgotten the doctype if it wasn't because working too fast.

Comment: I'm anyway... maintaining this question for others that may have the same problem, working too fast so that DOCTYPE was forgotten while hitting deadlines.

Comment: @Edward to avoid this in the future I suggest using `Emmet` plugin for you editor and using `html:5` shortcut to make basic tags html, head, body and Doctype. Hope it helps to avoid your issues. Emmet is also available out of the box in most editors. http://emmet.io/

Answer (score -1):

Where are you putting doctype at? because that is supposed to go at the way top of the page like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Rest of code here -->
```

Hope this helps. Come back if not.

Comment: The question says that there was no Doctype and one was added later. If it was added to the wrong place then it wouldn't make a different to the CSS rendering.

Comment: Yes, So I told him to add the DOCTYPE deceleration at the top. But if the CSS rendering is wrong he needs to add something else

Comment: As my previous comment said, the Doctype **was** added to the top. The CSS rendering is not wrong. The CSS rendering was wrong. The question is asking how to recreate (in standards mode) the effect that depended on the buggy quirks more rendering.